# Find same values from 2 df columns python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different dfs with the following columns:

```
col1                    col2

0 programming           0 programming
1 chess                 1 python
2 leadership            2 leadership
                        3 abba
                        4 games
```

I want to find what percentage of values of `col1` present in `col2`

For that, I thought I could construct a new df which will contain the same values and then its `len` to `len(col2)`. First I want to get this:

```
col3

0 programming
1 leadership
```

Here is what I tried, but I dont want to use two `for` loops

```
bb=[]
for i in company.col2:
    for b in student.col1:
        if i==b:
            bb.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(["programming", "chess", "leadership"], columns=["col1"])
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(["programming", "python", "leadership", "abba", "games"], columns=["col2"])
```

To find which values of `df1['col1']` are in `df2['col2']` use `isin`. The result is a boolean column. Use `sum` to find the number of values:

```
>>> df1['col1'].isin(df2['col2']).sum()
```

Use `size` to find the number of elements in `df2` and divide thus:

```
>>> df1['col1'].isin(df2['col2']).sum() / df2.size
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension, try the below

```
list1 = ["programming", "chess", "leadership"]
list2 = ["programming", "python", "leadership", "abba", "games"]
list3 = [value for value in list1 if value in list2]
```

> list3 = ["programming", "leadership"]

In your use case, you can just try the below.

```
list3 = [value for value in company.col2 if value in student.col1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas.merge to perform an inner join:

```
def main():

    df = pd.DataFrame(["programming", "chess", "leadership"], columns=["col1"])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(["programming", "python", "leadership", "abba", "games"], columns=["col2"])
    df3 = df.merge(df2, left_on="col1", right_on="col2", how="inner")
    print(df3["col1"])
```